# How can I optimize this Django query to get faster result?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, orm

```
items = Items.objects.filter(active=True)
price_list = []
for item in items:
   price = Price.objects.filter(item_id = item.id).last()
   price_list.append(price)
```

Price model can have multiple entry for single item, I have to pick last element. How can we optimize above query to avoid use of query in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item_ids = list(Items.objects.filter(active=True).values_list('id',flat=True))

price_list=Price.objects.filter(item_id__in=item_ids).values("item_id").order_by("-item_id").distinct("item_id")
```

Comment: distinct is an expensive process in SQL. Is there any other way possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Foreign Key to connect the Price and Item models, you can probably use this:

```
prices = Price.objects.filter(item__active=True)
```

Another approach would be to get the item ids first and then filter based on those (as Hemal has mentioned previously, however I believe that the query in Hemal's answer has a problem as it only provides the item ids whether the question needs the whole Price objects):

```
item_ids = Items.objects.filter(active=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
prices = Prices.objects.filter(item_id__in=item_ids)
```

Also, in the question, you are picking the last price, without ordering it on anything. I believe that you should order it on the specific field you want to ignore any non-determinism.

Comment: first approach won't work, as stated in question, Foreign key of item is added in price. The basic requirement is to get latest entry of item in price table as there can be multiple entries in price table for same item. I have to get latest price object of all the items.

according to your second approach, I will get all the multiple object of price for an item, but I need to get latest price for each item